# Exclude a delivery date based on product in cart for Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to exclude a certain delivery date on my delivery date picker on the checkout page, based on the product the customer has in the cart. E.g if someone has added product ID 6610 in their cart, I don't want them to be able to select the 14th Feb as a delivery date.

I cannot get this to work and I don't know why. Can anyone assist please? Thanks

```
// Hook into WooCommerce's "woocommerce_checkout_fields" filter
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'block_delivery_dates_checkout_form' );

function block_delivery_dates_checkout_form( $fields ) {
  // Array of dates to be blocked for the specified product
  $blocked_dates = array('2023-02-14');

  // Iterate over all products in the cart
  foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
    // Check if the product is the one we want to block delivery for
    if ( $cart_item['product_id'] == 6610 ) {
      // Loop through each date in the array of blocked dates
      foreach ( $blocked_dates as $date ) {
        // Add the date to the "exclude" option in the delivery date field
        $fields['delivery_date']['exclude'][] = $date;
      }
    }
  }

  return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Did you use another plugin in editing the checkout page?

Comment: Yes, we used WooCommerce Order Delivery to add the calendar.. but that's it. From what I can see, the field is still called delivery_date.